# Applescript to run javascript on chrome

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, javascript

Is there a way to run an Javascript using AppleScript

here is the JS :

```
javascript:Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('action-button')).forEach(function(v){v.removeAttribute("disabled");});
```

I tried this

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 2 of window 1 to set RemoveBtRestriction to execute javascript "javascript:Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('action-button')).forEach(function(v){v.removeAttribute("disabled");});"
end tell
```

but this return the error "Expected end of line but found identifier."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding single quotes around the word `"disabled"`.  Like this...

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 2 of window 1 to set RemoveBtRestriction to execute javascript ¬
        "javascript:Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('action-button'))
.forEach(function(v){v.removeAttribute('disabled');});"
end tell
```

I don't have a URL to test it on but at least the code compiles now